# Can't go below 16-17% body fat. What is wrong with my diet?

Tags: weightlifting, weight-loss, diet, gym, body-fat

I started to loose weight 1 year ago, when I began to practice MMA. Few months ago I realized I lost too much weight so I began weightlifting. I was around 79 kg ( 174 pounds ) last year and my current weight is 68.5 kg ( 151 pounds ) and I am about 179 cm tall ( 5 feet 10 inches). My scale shows me I have around 17-18% body fat.

My diet consists of:

1. **Breakfast - around 8:00 AM**

   - canned tuna in water ( 120g )
   - whole egg ( medium )
   - sometimes, but rarely ( since I try to cut )  1 smashed banana with oatmeal
2. **Snack - around 10:00 AM**

   - protein shake with water/milk ( 42g protein, 0.4g carbs, fiber 1.1g )
3. **Lunch**

   - usually chicken breast with cheese and rice/potatoes
4. **Snack - around 2:30 PM**

   - protein bar ( 16g protein, 25g carbs-15g simple sugars, fat 15g )
5. **Snack - around 5:00 PM**

   - greek plain yogurt
6. **Dinner - around 9:30 PM**

   - usually chicken breast with rice/potatoe, but in smaller portion than lunch

Thank you

Comment: Sounds to me like your way of measuring BF% is very inaccurate.

Comment: I'm not measuring myself. I have an electronic scale which calculates body  fat percentage, hydration level, muscle mass percentage and bone mass, but I don't think it shows the right value, because, I think it depends on the hydration level. When my hydration level is high ( highest was around 64.8% ), my muscle mass was also at the highest point ( around 48,8% ) and body fat was at the lowest point ( around 16.6% ).  But since then I get only 17-18% from it.

Comment: I've edited my question with the exact values shown by the electronic scale ( 13-14 was an approximation of mine, sorry )

Comment: I tried to approximate, because my current weight remained the same- around 68.5 kg ( 151 pounds ), but it's visible I have more muscle than few months ago, so that difference must be in body fat loss, but my electronic scale shows the same value for BF. I think I need a caliper.

Comment: @JJosaur - While they may be inaccurate, most scales stay at the same level of inaccuracy (So if they measure 5% low, they will always measure that). 13% is not "ridiculously low", and bodybuilders in competition are actually below 5%, many in the 1-2% range. This is (obviously) not sustainable for longer than a competition, however. But there are many many athletes that regularly maintain 6-10% bodyfat levels.

Comment: @Kosmo - As it is, your question is not really answerable You give rather vague representations of your food intake, and nothing about your workout regimens. Any answer would be throwing spaghetti at the wall.

Comment: There are several ways to measure body fat and household scale is the LEAST accurate i'd say. Find a qualified nutritionist or sports coach and have them measure you BF with calipers.

Comment: FWIW, bioelectrical impedance analysis (the method used by consumer grade scales) is more accurate for measuring changes in body fat percentage rather than actual percentage, so focus less on the value and more on the changes over time.  Measure yourself in the morning before you've eaten (fasting state).  If you really want an accurate reading, you'll need to do a hydrostatic weighing and/or DXA scan--these results can be compared against each other and are far more accurate than BIA.

Comment: Get some vegetables and fruit into your diet!  Hope you've been at least taking a multi-vitamin.

Comment: @Andrew.. yap I'm also eating tomatoes, sometimes spinach, carrots, cabbage..I'm taking centrum for man as vitamins

Comment: @JohnP Yeah sorry. I'm doing MMA 2/7 days per week and gym 3 or 4 days per week ( depending on the time I have that week ). I train hard, with max weight and usually my first 2 sets from every base exercise ( bench for chest, deadlifts and so on ) I am doing a drop set .
------------------
Everyone else: You are all right. I should get a better measurement for my BF before asking anything. I rashly asked, so sorry.

Comment: @Kosmo - No need to apologize. You now have information you didn't have before, that's why we are here. Most of this was intended to refine your question to get some good answers for you. :)

Comment: haha.  I was a bit alarmed when I saw the diet.  Good luck achieving your goals!

Comment: How many calories are those? What are you macros? Your nutrition looks so confused and wrong.

Comment: FDA recommends 2 serves of canned tuna a week due to mercury levels

Answer (score -3):

One thing you can do - move rice/potato from dinner to breakfast. No carbs at dinner. MMA and other fightings makes you weight stable. To run lower your BF percentage - go to fitness club and work with heavy iron. Heavy training accelerates your metabolism by 24 hours, while MMA 2-3 hours after training.

Comment: No carbs at dinner why? Where you base that? Work with heavy iron to lower bf? Again where is that based on? Those are not real advices.

Comment: This is a bunch of misinformation and poorly understood concepts.